# App will be approved by App Store or not if we pass a random number as device UDID to web server in the application?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, udid

Please suggest that if we have passed an random number as device UDID on web server. Then the app will be approved by App Store or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will not reject it for use of a random number, it is the unique identification of specific devices they are concerned about.

I do suggest you look into `identifierForVendor` and `advertisingIdentifier` as replacements for `uniqueIdentifier`.

If you need to support older iOS versions, you can build against a modern SDK, set your deployment version to the oldest version you support and check for the existence of these methods like so:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(identifierForVendor)])
{
   // Use the method here
}
else
{
   // Do something different for older iOS versions.
}
```

Comment: I have read in many notes that after replace the uniqueIdentifier with identifierForVendor and advertisingIdentifier, that  app will be support only ios 6.0 and later not older versions of ios.

Comment: I believe that would be correct, I have updated my answer to address this. However, keep in mind that [over 90% of iOS devices support iOS 6](http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/06/06/ahead-of-ios-7-reveal-apples-ios-6-is-on-93-of-iphones) as of this writing. You may wish to evaluate if supporting older versions is worth it for your app.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be rejected on that basis, it will get rejected if you use uniqueIdentifier of the device.

Although if you trying to use uniqueIdentifier, it will not pass validation while submitting to AppStore.

Comment: I have read in many notes that after replace the uniqueIdentifier with identifierForVendor and advertisingIdentifier, that app will be support only ios 6.0 and later not older versions of ios.

Answer (score 0):

Your app will not be rejected if you use random number as UDID, but it is not correct way to set random number as unique device id,because am number is generate repeatedly in random number generating, so these numbers are not unique.